# Haskell stack command line flag for executing an expression

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

If I have a simple Haskell one-liner, what's the flag in ghc or ghci that could execute this from the command line?

I'm looking for something like:

```
stack ghci -e 'putStrLn "hello world"'
```

Similar to

```
$ R --quiet -e "cat('hello world')"
> cat('hello world')
hello world>
```

or

```
$ python -c "print('hello world')"
hello world
```

### Edit for 'ghci -e' debug

(This question is resolved  with an excellent answer already, but just debugging that the flag seems like it /should/ work above...)

Weirdly couldn't get the seemingly supported `ghci -e` working for me.  Testing it is not just my machine, I also ran this on Ubuntu and had the same issue:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install  --yes curl \   
 && curl -sSL https://get.haskellstack.org/ | sh \
 && export HOME=/root/.local/bin:$HOME \
 && stack ghci -e 'putStrLn "hello world"'
```

Then

```
$ docker build .
```

Produced...

```
Stack has been installed to: /usr/local/bin/stack

WARNING: '/root/.local/bin' is not on your PATH.
    For best results, please add it to the beginning of PATH in your profile.

Invalid option `-e'

Usage: stack ghci [TARGET/FILE] [--ghci-options OPTIONS] [--ghc-options OPTIONS]
                  [--flag PACKAGE:[-]FLAG] [--with-ghc GHC] [--[no-]load]
                  [--package ARG] [--main-is TARGET] [--load-local-deps]
                  [--[no-]package-hiding] [--only-main] [--trace] [--profile]
                  [--no-strip] [--[no-]test] [--[no-]bench] [--help]
  Run ghci in the context of package(s) (experimental)
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update  && apt-get install  --yes curl  && curl -sSL https://get.haskellstack.org/ | sh  && export HOME=/root/.local/bin:$HOME  && stack ghci -e 'putStrLn "hello world"'' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: `stack eval 'putStrLn "hello world"'`

Comment: @Redu, this works, can you post as an answer I can accept?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you check `$ stack --help` at one point you see that

```
eval                     Evaluate some haskell code inline. Shortcut for
                         'stack exec ghc -- -e CODE'
```

So instead of doing like

```
$ stack exec ghc -- -e 'putStrLn "hello world"'
hello world
```

you may do like

```
$ stack eval 'putStrLn "hello world"'
hello world
```

Answer (score 2):

In fact you already have this [flag](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.6.2/docs/html/users_guide/modes.html): it is just:

> ```
> -e expr
> ```
>
> Evaluate `expr`; see eval-mode for details

So you can write it like:

```
ghci -e 'putStrLn "hello world"'
```

In fact if you use `stack ghci`, you just open `ghci` with your application, but the `-e` flag is not "stack-specific".

For example:

```
$ ghci -e 'putStrLn "hello world"'
hello world
```

Comment: Hmm, I get:

`$ stack ghci -e 'putStrLn "hello world"'
Invalid option `-e'
`
And don't otherwise have ghc installed outside of stack, if possible to keep it that way:

`$ ghc -e 'putStrLn "hello world"'

Command 'ghc' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install ghc
`

Comment: @Mittenchops: what version of `ghci` do you use? This is already supported since 7.6 (or even eariler) iirc.

Comment: `$ stack ghci
Configuring GHCi with the following packages: 
GHCi, version 8.4.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help`

Comment: @Mittenchops: in 8.4.3, this flag is also supported: https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/8.4.3/docs/html/users_guide/flags.html#ghc-flag--e%20%E2%9F%A8expr%E2%9F%A9, strange

Comment: I have a resolution to the major question, but I am interested in this.  It doesn't seem to be the case on ubuntu somehow?  Let me add an edit in the question to clarify.

Comment: @Mittenchops: well I work with Ubuntu as well, so this makes it even more strange :S